# Hive everything imported as string when using com.bizo.hive.serde.csv.CSVSerde

Tags: hadoop, hive

I downloaded the stackoverflow user dump, so that I could get accustomed to hive, and I've converted the xml to a csv file. I'm using the following:

```
add jar /home/cloudera/csv-serde.jar;
drop table stackoverflow_users;

CREATE external TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stackoverflow_users (CreationDate timestamp, Views BIGINT,
  AccountId BIGINT, AboutMe string,
  WebsiteUrl string, LastAccessDate timestamp, upvotes bigint,
  ProfileImageUrl string, DisplayName string,
  Id BigInt, Reputation BIGINT, DownVotes bigint,
  Age int, Location String)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.bizo.hive.serde.csv.CSVSerde'
location '/user/cloudera/users';
```

And the file rows are in the following format:

```
"2008-08-01T12:09:11.010","1347","14","","http://some.url","2016-01-15T01:44:05.733","369","","User name","20","6943","38","","Some location"
"2008-08-01T12:11:11.897","830","15","","http://some.url","2016-06-11T01:38:09.770","191","","User name","22","8727","5","30","Some location"
```

However, if I do a `desc stackoverflow_users`, I see the following:

```
+------------------+------------+--------------------+--+
|     col_name     | data_type  |      comment       |
+------------------+------------+--------------------+--+
| creationdate     | string     | from deserializer  |
| views            | string     | from deserializer  |
| accountid        | string     | from deserializer  |
| aboutme          | string     | from deserializer  |
| websiteurl       | string     | from deserializer  |
| lastaccessdate   | string     | from deserializer  |
| upvotes          | string     | from deserializer  |
| profileimageurl  | string     | from deserializer  |
| displayname      | string     | from deserializer  |
| id               | string     | from deserializer  |
| reputation       | string     | from deserializer  |
| downvotes        | string     | from deserializer  |
| age              | string     | from deserializer  |
| location         | string     | from deserializer  |
+------------------+------------+--------------------+--+
```

Why is it that everything is a string?

Comment: Could be an issue with the serde: https://github.com/ogrodnek/csv-serde/issues/26

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue lies with the SerDe used. It's also reported [here](http://github.com/ogrodnek/csv-serde/issues/26)